# Controller for each user in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to make a website like ask.fm, each user will have a profile, the link to this profile will be something like (http://ask.fm/userx), I will use ASP.NET Core MVC, but I don't know how to make controller for each user ?

I know routes will be (http://ask.fm/controller/action), but I need (http://ask.fm/userx), how to do that ? where to start ?

Comment: do you really mean each user need a different ***dynamic*** controller? or at least many related stuff (including services, configuration ...) are specific to the user? That's close to the requirement of building a multi-tenant site. Otherwise if it's just a difference in the route (path, url) among users, then it's a lot easier.

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean I don't know where to start to achieve that

Comment: *where to start* is equal to *how to do* but here we need to make clear ***what is needed***. And you should be the one knowing that clearly.

Comment: have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks @NevilleNazerane